# Not able to ping Windows Host from WSL2

Tags: windows-10, networking, ubuntu, docker, wsl2

I have enabled WSL2 on my Windows 10 desktop. Till recently, I was able to reach/connect to applications installed on Host from WSL2. However, now for testing purposes when I ping the host, I get "Destination Host Unreachable".

An interesting observation is that once I restart WSL2 from PowerShell

```
Get-Service LxssManager | Restart-Service
```

and quickly ping HOST on WSL command prompt, I get to see successful responses for initial requests, but eventually, the host becomes unreachable.

```
user@MACHINEM5D:/mnt/c/windows/system32$ ping host.docker.internal
PING host.docker.internal (192.168.29.99) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from host.docker.internal (192.168.29.99): icmp_seq=1 ttl=127 time=0.772 ms
64 bytes from host.docker.internal (192.168.29.99): icmp_seq=2 ttl=127 time=0.676 ms
From 192.168.16.1 (192.168.16.1) icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.16.1 (192.168.16.1) icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.16.1 (192.168.16.1) icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Also, from WSL2 I can reach the internet.

```
user@MACHINEM5D:/mnt/c/windows/system32$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8

user@MACHINEM5D:/mnt/c/windows/system32$ ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.167.206) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from del03s18-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.167.206): icmp_seq=1 ttl=117 time=104 ms
64 bytes from del03s18-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.167.206): icmp_seq=2 ttl=117 time=105 ms
64 bytes from del03s18-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.167.206): icmp_seq=3 ttl=117 time=109 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
```

On Windows hosts file has the following entries

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost
# Added by Docker Desktop
192.168.29.99 host.docker.internal
192.168.29.99 gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

The output of /etc/hosts on WSL2.

```
user@MACHINEM5D:/mnt/c/windows/system32$ cat /etc/hosts
# This file was automatically generated by WSL. To stop automatic generation of this file, add the following entry to /etc/wsl.conf:
# [network]
# generateHosts = false
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       INNOXXXXXX5D.XXX.XXX.XXX

127.0.0.1       localhost
::1     localhost
192.168.29.99   host.docker.internal
192.168.29.99   gateway.docker.internal
127.0.0.1       kubernetes.docker.internal

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Something that I have also checked is that the I am able to ping WLS2 eth0 IP from Windows Host.

```
C:\Users\XXXX27>ping 172.18.81.68

Pinging 172.18.81.68 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 172.18.81.68: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.18.81.68: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.18.81.68: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 172.18.81.68: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 172.18.81.68:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

Something that was earlier working was accessing MYSQL installed on Windows Host from WSL2. It has stopped working.

```
user@MACHINEM5D:/mnt/c/windows/system32$ mysql -u auth_user -p teamup_auth -h 192.168.29.99
Enter password:
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.29.99:3306' (113)
```

I would appreciate any suggestions to resolve this issue.

Thanks,

Nitin

Comment: I suggest using the address in `/etc/resolv.conf` or alternatively the default gateway instead. What Docker does is not guaranteed to work outside Docker.

Comment: @NitinJ Thanks for the update.  So that's good, of course -- And I'm still not quite sure what's going on here.  Does it make any difference if you turn back on the WSL `/etc/resolv.conf` generation?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds - I have reverted back to the automatic generation of `/etc/resolv.conf` by WSL, but the issue persists. Thanks!

Comment: @NitinJ Still noodling on it - You definitely have some weirdness going on.  What WSL version are you on?  (In other words) Have you updated (can you) to the new WSL *application* (1.0.0) from the Microsoft Store?

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds - I might have made a mistake in validating the issue after configuring automatic generation of `/etc/resolv.conf`. Now, when I use the IP address against the `nameserver` to ping the HOST machine, I get 0% packet loss. Thanks!

Comment: @NitinJ Wow - Great to hear!  I'm still a little confused as to exactly *why* that's the case, but it was certainly the first troubleshooting step in my arsenal, of course ;-).

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to use a network name that is specific to Docker Desktop. Do not use this name when not working with Docker Desktop specifically. It may be available for technical reasons while Docker Desktop is running but you still should not use it otherwise.

Instead, follow the [Microsoft recommended way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/networking#accessing-windows-networking-apps-from-linux-host-ip) and retrieve the internal host IP address from `resolv.conf`:

```
grep "nameserver" /etc/resolv.conf | awk '{print $2}'
```

A well-known host name alias *does not exist* by default. You can use `pcname.local` where `pcname` is your PC’s network name. Do not leave out the `.local`.

Furthermore, keep in mind that real access (beyong ping) will be problematic because, as far as the Windows firewall is concerned, the WSL network is “Public”. Different, more restrictive firewall rules will apply. Because the WSL network is somewhat hidden, you will not get a “Allow this app” popup. You must use the advanced firewall configuration to manually enable or create the required rules.

---

WSL 2 does not use addresses in *192.168/16* at all by default. Instead, at every boot, it picks a random subnet from *172.16/12*.

Comment: Not sure about the rest of it, but I'm fairly sure that `pcname.local` won't work for the OP since they aren't using the WSL resolver.

Comment: Also, I've always received the "Allow this app" popup the first time I access a Windows service from inside WSL2.  Unfortunately, it typically gets hidden behind another window, since the terminal where I'm typing is still active.  If the user misses it (which I *often* did before I started looking for the popup *behind* other windows), then the default "Deny" policy will be put into place automatically until and unless the user sees the window and selects "Allow".

Comment: If either an Allow or Deny policy is already in place, then the "Allow this app" popup will *not* appear.  It's possible to reset back to the default state by opening the advanced firewall configuration and *deleting* the existing (allow or deny) rules for that service.

Comment: Yeah that’s my point: You only see this popups once, don’t tick “Public”, now they won’t show again. // You may be right about the resolver, but that’s up to OP to figure out.